# PrintStream printing late, prints after input

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting my PrintStream to work correctly. I built a basic chatroom with commands (excuse my code if its messy, I just kind of threw it together) But the enter your name print statement only runs AFTER the name is inputted. So it hangs with a cursor until text is submitted then prints

```
    Test (This is the input)
    Enter your name: 
    Welcome to the channel Test. Current members: Test,
```

The first line is the input and the second and third is the resulting print statement. Is there a solution I'm missing? (All appropriate classes have been imported)

```
public class FinalProjectClientThread extends Thread
{
public DataInputStream is = null;
public PrintStream os = null;
public Socket clientSocket = null;
public final FinalProjectClientThread[] threads;
public int clientCount;
public String ClientName;
private boolean isModerator;
private boolean isMuted;

public FinalProjectClientThread(Socket clientSocket, FinalProjectClientThread[] threads)
{
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    clientCount = threads.length;
    isModerator = false;
}
public String getClientName()
{
    return ClientName;
}
private void setClientName(String n)
{
    ClientName = n;
}
public void stopServer()
{
    System.exit(0);
}
public void kickUser()
{
    try
    {
    clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
}
public void muteUser()
{
    isMuted = true;
}
public void run()
{
    int maxClients = this.clientCount;
    FinalProjectClientThread[] threads = this.threads;
    try
    {
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      os.flush();
      os.print("");
      os.flush();
      os.print("Enter your name: ");
      os.flush();
      String name = is.readLine();
      this.setClientName(name);
      os.print("\nWelcome to the channel " + name+". ");
      os.flush();
      //Count number of users in channel
      int count = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
      {
          if(threads[i]!=null&&threads[i].getClientName() != null)
          {
              count++;
          }
      }
      //Print text based on number
      if(count == 0)
      {
          os.println("There are no other members.");
          os.flush();
      }
      else
      {
          os.print("Current members: ");
          os.flush();
      }
      //Print member's names
      for(int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
      {
          if(threads[i]!=null&&threads[i].getClientName() != null)
          {
              os.print(threads[i].getClientName()+ ", ");
              os.flush();
          }
      }
      os.println();
      os.flush();


      for(int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
      {
        if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this)
        {
          threads[i].os.println(name + " has joined the channel");
        }
      }
      while (true)
      {
        String line = is.readLine();
        if (line.equals("/leave"))
        {
          break;
        }
        else if(line.equals("/mod"))
        {
            os.println("Enter the moderator code: ");
            String line2 = is.readLine();
            if(line2.equals("hurricanemod"))
            {
                isModerator = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
            {
              if (threads[i] != null)
              {
                threads[i].os.println(name+" is now a moderator");
              }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                os.println("That code is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else if(line.equals("/help"))
        {
            os.print("The following commands are valid: leave, help, mod, kick, mute, unmute");
        }
        else if(line.indexOf("/kick") == 0)
        {
            if(isModerator)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
                {
                    if(threads[i] != null && threads[i].getClientName().equals(line.substring(6, line.length())))
                    {
                        threads[i].kickUser();
                    }
                }
                os.println("User kicked");
            }
            else
            {
                os.println("You must be a moderator to kick people. Use /mod and the code provided by the server hoster");
            }
        }
        else if(line.equals("/stop"))
        {
            if(isModerator)
            {
                this.stopServer();
            }
            else
            {
                os.println("You must be a moderator to stop the server. Use /mod and the code provided by the server hoster");
            }
        }
        else if(line.indexOf("/mute") == 0)
        {
            if(isModerator)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
                {
                    if(threads[i] != null && threads[i].getClientName().equals(line.substring(6, line.length())))
                    {
                        threads[i].muteUser();
                    }
                }
                os.println(line.substring(6, line.length())+ " was muted.");
            }
            else
            {
                os.println("You must be a moderator to kick people. Use /mod and the code provided by the server hoster");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!isMuted)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
                {
                    if (threads[i] != null)
                    {
                        threads[i].os.println(name+": " + line);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                os.println("You are muted");
            }
        }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
      {
        if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this)
        {
          threads[i].os.println(name + " left the channel");
        }
      }
      os.println("You have left the channel");
      for (int i = 0; i < maxClients; i++)
      {
        if (threads[i] == this)
        {
          threads[i] = null;
        }
      }
      is.close();
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("IOExcepetion(Thread)");
    }
}





}
```

Server

```
public class FinalProjectServer
{
private static Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
private static ServerSocket serverSocket  = null;
private static Socket clientSocket = null;
private static int clientCount = 10;
private static FinalProjectClientThread[] clientList = new FinalProjectClientThread[clientCount];


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /*System.out.print("Enter port for server to run on: ");
    int port = kb.nextInt();*/
    int port = 25565;
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException");
    }
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            int i = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < clientCount; i++)
            {
                if(clientList[i] == null)
                {
                    clientList[i] = new FinalProjectClientThread(clientSocket,clientList);
                    clientList[i].start();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i == clientCount)
            {
                PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                os.println("Max number of client reached. Please contact server host.");
                os.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Client

```
public class FinalProjectClient implements Runnable
{
  private static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  // The client socket
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  // The output stream
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  // The input stream
  private static DataInputStream is = null;
  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the IP of the host computer: ");
    String IP = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the port number: ");
    int port = kb.nextInt();
    try
    {
        clientSocket = new Socket(IP, port);
        inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Can not find host, Unknown");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException");
    }
    try
    {
        new Thread(new FinalProjectClient()).start();
        while(!closed)
        {
            os.println(inputLine.readLine());
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public void run()
{
    String reply;
    try
    {
        while((reply = is.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(reply);
            if(reply.indexOf("/leave") != -1)
                break;
        }
        closed = true;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Its really difficult to read through the chunk of code which is not even properly indented. Consider 1. Taking care of formatting and Indentations correctly. 2. Instead of putting entire code provide snippet and more of a background

Comment: I apologize this is my first post here and I was not sure how to properly post. Is there any other information that you might need?